# MySQL: row is not updating when query execute by $_GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a problem again with my MySQL query. I am trying to execute my query using my $_GET variable. so here is my code. and many thanks in advance and answer will be very appreciated.

and please dont down vote my question if anyone thinks its not correct, please edit it or tell me to edit it.

many thanks.
here is Code.

```
 $Status = $_GET['status'];
 $User = $_GET['user'];

    require('./connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if ($numrows > 0) {
        echo '<table class="table" border="1">
        <tr style="background-color: #0DF; color: #222; font-weight:bold;">
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td>Domain:</td>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>Plan:</td>
            <td>Duration:</td>
            <td>Payable:</td>
            <td>Paid Date:</td>
            <td>Active Plan:</td>
            <td>Active:</td>
            <td>Register Date:</td>
        </tr>';

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $dbid = $row['id'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbemail = $row['email'];
            $dbfname = $row['first_name'];
            $dblname = $row['last_name'];
            $dbdomain = $row['domain'];
            $dbcountry = $row['country'];
            $dbphone = $row['phone'];
            $dbplan = $row['plan'];
            $dbduration = $row['duration'];
            $dbpayable = $row['payable'];
            $dbpaid_date = $row['paid_date'];
            $dbactive_plan = $row['active_plan'];
            $dbactive = $row['active'];
            $dbdate = $row['date'];
            if ( $dbactive_plan == 0) {
                $status = "Activate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=1&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
            else {
                $status = "Deactivate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=0&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$dbid.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbuser.' <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?id='.$dbid.'">Delete</a></td>
                <td>'.$dbemail.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbfname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dblname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdomain.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbcountry.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbphone.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbplan.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbduration.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpayable.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpaid_date.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive_plan.' '.$changeStatus.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdate.'</td>
            </tr>';


        }//while loop
        echo '</table>';
        if ($Status == 1 && $User == $dbuser) {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET active_plan='$Status' WHERE username='$User'";
            mysqli_query($con, $query);
            echo "$Status";
        }
        else if ($Status == 0 && $User == $dbuser) {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET active_plan='$Status' WHERE username='$User'";
            mysqli_query($con, $query);
            echo "$Status";
        }
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: Where is `$_GET` in your code? Can't find it and can not understand your question.

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT")` is missing?

Comment: code is updated. please look.

Comment: but its only update last row not from any other row.

Comment: Why u need update statement 2 times for same job :) ... incorrect logic .

Comment: Also update statements needs to be inside the while loop

Comment: if update statements inside while loop it applies on all users. i tried that. and I dont want that.

Comment: thanks, u were right, that update statement needs to be inside loop. that works. But that was not working earlier and I dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining `$dbuser` inside the `while` loop, so it is getting set to the username from the last iteration of the loop. I'm not sure based on your code what `$dbuser` is supposed to be, judging by your code....

Comment: So where should I place `$dbuser` ?

Comment: Well, you tell me. You have a condition that says `if ($Status == 1 && $User == $dbuser)`, so you're checking if the user is (someone). What do you intend to check with this statement? Who does the user need to be to execute this update?